# Are there any O.S.Card's works that follow what happens to Bean post-"Shadow of the Giant"?

Tags: orson-scott-card, enders-game

At the end of Orson Scott Card's "[Shadow of the Giant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_of_the_Giant)",

> Bean - with his 3 children having "Anton's key" turned on - flies from Earth on a newly developed fast messenger starship, hoping for one of the 2 outcomes - either he and his children will eventually die prevening the gene from spreading; or IF research into turning off Anton's key works and they can be cured. Bean himself is very skeptical of the likelyhood of that research working, and, at the end of his life, so is the Hegemon.

**Are there any other works - "Children of the Mind" trilogy, some new books or short stories or Card's published future plans - that detail what happened to Bean after that?**

Please note that I'm asking specifically about Bean's further story, **not** that of the single "missing" Bean's child that's covered in "Ender in Exile".

Comment: According to OCS [forum post](http://www.hatrack.com/cgi-bin/ubbmain/ultimatebb.cgi?ubb=print_topic;f=1;t=002910), he's working on the "in" series. 'We'll call them the "in" series. Shadows in Flight, Ender in Exile, **Mazer in Kindergarten**'.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There will be two novels that continue Bean's story. [Shadows in Flight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadows_in_Flight) was published January 17, 2012 and features Bean some time after Shadow of the Giant. It will be followed at some point by [Shadows Alive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadows_Alive), which will also continue the plot from Children of the Mind and is expected to be the final novel in the universe.