# Is Orson Scott Card adding any more novels to the Ender's Game universe?

Tags: enders-game, orson-scott-card

Is Orson Scott Card adding any more novels to the Ender's Game universe? I am still working through them but it seems there are a bunch of chronologically convoluted additions that aren't mentioned entirely in one database. Even the lists in the books are incomplete.

For the purpose of working out the order of how i read them, is there anymore more "known" or speculated additions to this universe?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any O.S.Card's works that follow what happens to Bean post-"Shadow of the Giant"?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6965/are-there-any-o-s-cards-works-that-follow-what-happens-to-bean-post-shadow-of)

Comment: Also look out for the upcoming 7-part "Ender's Barber" series

Comment: Ender's Barber? Isn't that the one he was ordered to write by the tax court?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least one is planned for the side-series known as the "[Shadow saga](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ender%27s_Game_series#Shadow_saga)" or (from the name of the first book in that series) the "[Ender's Shadow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ender%27s_Shadow) books".  It is currently set to be called [Shadows Alive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadows_Alive):

> Shadows Alive is a planned science fiction novel by Orson Scott Card in the Ender's Game series. It will link the Ender's Shadow books back to the Ender Saga.
>   
>   Card has said that Shadows Alive will wrap up some of the plot threads left dangling in Shadow of the Giant (the fourth Shadow book). The book will pick up from where Children of the Mind (the final book in the Ender quartet) left off. This novel was originally to be part of Shadows in Flight, but has since separated to Shadows Alive.

Additionally, a [3-part prequel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ender%27s_Game_series#The_First_Formic_War) still has the 3rd part to come:

> Card and Aaron Johnston have planned a trilogy to cover events in the First Formic War. Earth Unaware, a prequel to the entire Ender series, was released on July 17, 2012. Earth Afire, was released on June 4, 2013, followed by Earth Awakens in 2014.

Additionally, given the success of the first prequels, the contract for the second prequels has been signed: http://www.endersansible.com/2013/11/04/aaron-johnston-confirms-second-formic-war-trilogy/